# Google Sheet Script is copying values twice

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I wrote the following code to run whenever a specific column in the "BOS" sheet is edited. The timestamp works great but the second part of the code runs twice and I'm not sure why that's the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Checks to make sure the right sheet and cell were edited
  if( s.getName() == "BOS") {
    var ac = s.getActiveCell();
    if( ac.getColumn() == 12) {

      // Adds a timestamp when a new url is posted
      var nextCell = ac.offset(0, 1);
      var date = Date();
      nextCell.setValue(date);

      // Copies the row to the History sheet
      var row = ac.getRow();
      var rangeToCopy = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 13);
      var destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("History");
      var destAvals = destination.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
      var destAlast = destAvals.filter(String).length;;
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(destination.getRange((destAlast + 1), 1), {contentsOnly: true});    
    };
  };
}
```

Comment: add output on sheet please.  This is a wall of code.

Comment: What second part?  What part runs twice?  If that code runs twice, then it can't be the code.  That code can't run twice unless something else is happening.  Is there any way that it could be getting called twice?

Comment: @NathanielJohnson  how can I add output to the sheet? Sorry not super familiar with JS/Google Scripts

Comment: @SandyGood I'm referring to the "Copies the row to the History sheet" section. When I make an edit to column L in the "BOS" sheet, it adds two identical rows to the "History" sheet

Comment: After the line: `var destAlast = destAvals.filter(String).length;`  Add a `Logger.log('destAlast: ' + destAlast)` statement.  Run the code, and then VIEW the LOGS.  From the View menu choose Logs.  Tell us what the value of `destAlast` is.

Comment: @SandyGood [17-03-22 18:02:53:120 PDT] destAlast: 6

Comment: The range to copy is: `var rangeToCopy = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 13);` So, it's only getting one row and 13 columns.  The destination range is row 7, column 1.  From that code, I don't know why the result would be that the values are copied twice.  I don't know if it's a bug?  Did you "install" an "On Edit" trigger.  The function name `onEdit()` is a reserved word function name that does not need to be "installed" to run.

Answer (score 0):

@SandyGood was correct, there was an installed onEdit trigger running as well so it triggered twice. Thanks!